# Handling Multi Dimensional Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a project using JS. Being unfamiliar with JS I'd like to ask how I can tackle my current issue. I'm trying to handle some data and I've structured these arrays as provided. I'm pretty certain this doesn't work, but if someone can guide me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
var data=[][][]
data[0][][]="Eating Establishments"
data[0][0][]="Stan's Diner"
data[0][0][0]=[]
data[0][0][1]=[]
data[0][0][2]=[]
data[0][0][3]=[]
data[0][0][4]=[]
data[0][0][5]=[]
data[0][0][6]=[]
data[0][1][]="Booster Juice"
data[0][1][0]=[]
data[0][1][1]=[]
data[0][1][2]=[]
data[0][1][3]=[]
data[0][1][4]=[]
data[0][1][5]=[]
data[0][1][6]=[]
data[0][2][]="Pizza Pizza"
data[0][2][0]=[]
data[0][2][1]=[]
data[0][2][2]=[]
data[0][2][3]=[]
data[0][2][4]=[]
data[0][2][5]=[]
data[0][2][6]=[]
```

Comment: what you need looks more like `var data=[[[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]]` to support a 3-level root with 6 level sub arrays (ignoring the redundant `0` level shown in the assignments above... yes, there is a better way to do this, factories come to mind.

Comment: please add the structure, you need.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using such deeply nested arrays rather than an object structure? For instance `var categories = [ { name: "Eating Establishments", items: [ { name: "Stan's Diner" }, { name: "Booster Juice" } ] } ];` etc.

Comment: Im completely new to JS. Coming from other languages...I guess ill check out factories and object structure but hwy all the down votes lol

Answer (score 1):

To create the multi dimensional array you should use :

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i!=3; i++){
    data[i] = [];
    for(var y = 0; y!=6; y++){
        data[i][y] = []
    }
}
```